# how to override [] brackets in ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, select, escaping

I am writing an Ajax request form with Ruby on Rails using a `collection_select` tag that looks like this:

```
<%= collection_select("Jobs", "clearance", @allClearances, "clearance", "clearance", {:prompt => "Select a Clearance"} )%>
```

Ruby then builds an HTML select tag with `id = "Jobs_clearance"` and `name = "Jobs[clearance]"`

I want to send the parameter to my controller, which looks like this:

```
class JobsController < ApplicationController
  def foo
    @clearance = params[:Jobs[clearance]]
  end
```

Unfortunately, Ruby only reads `":Jobs"` as the symbol instead of `":Jobs[clearance]"`
Is there a way to escape the `[]`'s? backslash isn't working.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to use `params[:Jobs][:clearance]`

`params` is a hash of all the request parameters.  But `params[:Jobs`] is ALSO a hash of all :Jobs parameters.  So calling `params[:Jobs][:clearance]` is calling the `[]` method on the `params[:Jobs]` object passing `:clearance` in as a parameter.

Answer (score 55):

kmorris solved your problem (very well) but i would like to answer your question:
you can override [] and []= operators because they are methods (like almost everything), but you should think well about what you are doing because you can break tons of things.

```
class AntiArray < Array

  def [](ind)
    self.fetch(-ind)
  end

end

y = AntiArray.new([1,2,3,4])

y[1]

=> 4
```

Answer (score 0):

@German, tried to get answer for your question.

```
2.1.3 :025 > class AntiArray < Array
2.1.3 :026?>     def [](ind)
2.1.3 :027?>         self.fetch(-ind) + 1
2.1.3 :028?>     end
2.1.3 :029?>   end
 => :[] 
2.1.3 :030 > y = AntiArray.new([1,2,3,4])
 => [1, 2, 3, 4] 
2.1.3 :031 > y[1]
 => 5 
2.1.3 :032 >
```

Hope this is what you are asking for. Given a try for you