# Are there methods for enabling Hash-style look-ups in custom classes?

Tags: ruby

I'm pretty sure there are some methods I can implement in my classes to make look-ups like this possible:

```
foo = MyClass.new
foo["bar"] = 123
```

But what are they?

Comment: [OpenStruct](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0/libdoc/ostruct/rdoc/OpenStruct.html) may be of interest to you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can always define your own `[]` and `[]=` methods (google: "operator overloading")
e.g.:

```
class MyClass
  def [](key)
    # ...
  end

  def []=(key, value)
    # ... 
  end
end
```

Here are some examples:

http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ruby/ruby-for-newbies-operators-and-their-methods/

https://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/4067570

[how to override [] brackets in ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/971076/how-to-override-brackets-in-ruby)

Comment: Those are exactly the methods I was looking for! Thanks

Comment: @Codemonkey Ruby core class `Struct` and stand lib `osstruct` built already these functionality,then why the double work...? :)

Comment: Because you might not want to base your class on `Struct` or `OpenStruct`.   `OpenStruct` is very slow btw. - not recommended for large number of objects.

Comment: @ArupRakshit: I just want the key/value syntax for a cache system I'm making. It's based on SQLite3 and I don't actually need any hashes or structs for that.

Comment: `[]=` should take (at least) two arguments: the key and the new value.