# How can I override Hash native brackets ([] access)

Tags: ruby, hash, overriding

I want to override the Hash class native brackets in ruby.

Note I don't want to override them in a class that inherits from Hash (no subclassing), I want to actually override Hash itself, such that any hash anywhere will always inherit my behavior.

Specifically (bonus points for..) - I want this in order to natively emulate a *hash with indifferent access*. In JavaScript I would modify the `prototype`, Ruby is known for its metaprogramming, so I hope this is possible.

So what I am aiming for is:

```
>> # what do I do here to overload Hash's []?...
>> x = {a:123} # x is a native Hash
>> x[:a] # == 123, as usual
>> x['a'] # == 123, hooray!
```

I've tried: 
1)

```
class Hash
  define_method(:[]) { |other| puts "Hi, "; puts other }
end
```

and

```
class Hash
  def []
    puts 'bar'
  end
end
```

Both crash irb.

Comment: Please show what have you tried so far

Comment: show us what have you tried

Comment: Uh... two approaches for example (that can't get off the ground, irb crashes when running them): 
1) class Hash; define_method(:[]) { |other| puts "Hi, "; puts other } end
2) class Hash; def [](key) puts key; end 

Worth noting that it is possible to override in a subclass (http://stackoverflow.com/a/974442/954741), but I can't manage to override native hashes.

Comment: ActiveSupport offers hash with indifferent access...

Comment: Yes, I am familiar with hash_with_indifferent_access and similar solutions - I specifically want to modify native hashes, so that any hash anywhere will be with indifferent access.

Comment: Even if you manage to implement it, I may turn out to be unpractical, possibly because it's too slow or because some libraries beyond your control may rely on `x[:answer] = 42; x.keys == [:answer]` (or similar invariants) being true for `Hash`.

Comment: Even if you manage to override `[]` or `[]=`, it may not not be enough, because some C and Ruby libraries may be using other methods (or C functions) to access the keys in the hash. So you'll have to override many (dozens of methods).

Comment: @pts - that's a good point, but not a sure case and it's worth trying. 'Access by wrong type' (string/symbol) errors is a major headache.

Comment: IRb is written in Ruby, and thus is pretty likely to use `Hash`es itself. It is no wonder that such a brutal crippling of `Hash#[]` will crash it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This seems to get the job done.

```
class Hash
  def [](key)
    value = (fetch key, nil) || (fetch key.to_s, nil) || (fetch key.to_sym, nil)     
  end

  def []=(key,val)
    if (key.is_a? String) || (key.is_a? Symbol) #clear if setting str/sym
        self.delete key.to_sym
        self.delete key.to_s        
    end
    merge!({key => val})
  end
end
```

And now:

```
user = {name: 'Joe', 'age' => 20} #literal hash with both symbols and strings as keys
user['name'] == 'Joe' # cool!
user[:age] == 20      # cool!
```

For more details see: http://www.sellarafaeli.com/blog/ruby_monkeypatching_friendly_hashes

Comment: @sellarfaeli, when you grow up more as a Rubyist, you will have good memories of your foolish youthful adventures with overriding `Hash#[]` and `#[]=` lol.

Answer (score 3):

```
class Hash
  def [] key
    value = fetch key rescue
    case key
    when Symbol then "#{value}, as usual"
    when String then "#{value}, hooray!"
    else value end
  end
end
```

Comment: Also won't work across Ruby versions because irb. Irb is a special case.

Comment: Crashes my irb. But brought me very close (see my answer) so upvoting! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If using Rails [HashWithIndifferentAccess](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/HashWithIndifferentAccess.html) supports this functionality already, even if using Ruby you can weigh including Active Support to have this functionality.