# How does '#[](argument)' work?

Tags: ruby, methods

I've come across the following code:

```
class Duration    
  def self.[](magnitude)
     ...
  end
end
```

I can do the following:

```
Duration.[]("2 weeks")
```

as well as this:

```
Duration["2 weeks"]
```

How is the value `"2 weeks"` that I put inside of the `[ ]` passed as the argument to the method?

Comment: It's unusual. Maybe this helps? https://stackoverflow.com/a/974442/541091 `[]` is a method like all operators in Ruby but usually it would be used to access some kind of enumerable by index. In this case it looks like it just instantiates a `Duration` by calling `Duration#new`.

Comment: Its by design. At what level are you asking this question? You want to know how it is implemented in C?

Comment: It's the kind of syntactic sugar that also allows you to write `1 + 2` instead of `1.+(2)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because the Ruby language is designed that way.

Let's take the following example.

```
array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Here both of the following codes produce the same result.

```
puts array[2]
puts array.[](2)
```

Ruby's Array class has the following method

```
[](index)
```

This method returns the element at the specified index.

```
array[2]
```

is also interpreted as

```
array.[](2)
```

before calculating the result.

Hope this helps you.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I get what you say about the array. I guess I should ask what does  .[](argument) mean? Is it calling some method?

Comment: @chell Yes, that's exactly what it's doing. [] is the method that's being called.

Answer (score 1):

Answering to your question in the comment to @Nabin Paudyal answer.
The line

```
def self.[](magnitude)
```

inside the `class Duration` body means in English (ruby flavored):

"open the singleton class of object `Duration` and add to it 'instance method' for object (in our case object of `Class` class -  named `Duration`)"

Usually it should looks like:

```
def self.method_name(arguments)
```

After this you may call it like this:

```
object.method_name(arguments)
```

In your case the name of the object is `Duration` (a class) and the name of the method is `[]`.
Thus the call should look like this:

```
Duration.[](argument)
```

In other words you are perfectly right. It is "calling some method".